# Where in a PEM (SSL) file is the passphrase stored? If you open a .pem file in a text editor, can you steal the passphrase?

Tags: ssl, certificate, pem

I'm trying to understand how a .pem file is laid out. How is the passphrase authenticated? How does the .pem file check against itself the passphrase you try to open it with?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple different kinds of data are stored in files with the extension .pem. So your question is imprecise. But suppose it is a password-protected private key file. Why do you believe the password is stored anywhere in it? In fact it is not stored in the file. The passphrase is used to generate a symmetric key, which is used to decrypt the file and check the decrypted file for consistency.

Comment: So there's no way you can decipher the passphrase that protects it by viewing the contents of the .pem file in a text editor?

Comment: No, you cannot figure out the passphrase by viewing the contents in any editor.

Comment: Thank you. So, unless you have the passphrase, you can't use the .pem file in any practical application.